# Renaming Computer name on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had to change the computer name from x to y on a sql server 2008  r2. And followed the instructions 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx]

Now when I select @@servername it shows null.

However when I Query 
Select * from sys.servers, the new server name is listed..

@@Servername is used in many of stored procs..

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is that you have to specify 'local' when adding the server after deleting..
now it shows the server name

Here is the link..
http://techontip.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/rename-sql-server-2008-single-server-senario/

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved.  You should choose this as the answer to your question.